# How to apply css styles defined in html head to complete report in iReport?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I want to include my own css styles while generating the report. Iam using iReport for report generation. I successfully set the html_header by setting the `JRHtmlExporterParameter.HTML_HEADER`. When i run the ireport the header value has the link tag with corresponding href.

```
<html><head><title></title><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/><style type="text/css">a {text-decoration: none}</style></head><body text="#000000" link="#000000" alink="#000000" vlink="#000000"><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td width="50%">&nbsp;</td><td align="center"><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/apsrtc-oprs/_assets/skin/style.css" /> <center><a name="JR_PAGE_ANCHOR_0_1"></a>
```

My question is how do i apply the defined css-style to the complete iReport ?

Any suggestions are welcome.